# Check several option types and then convert to type

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union, option-type

I am a new programmer in general, and as well to F#.  I've ran into this particular problem several times, and have yet to solve it efficiently in my opinion. Here is the problem:

I have these example types:

```
 type Retail1 = | Fashion | Auto | Sports
 type Wholesale1 = | Fashion | Auto | Sports
 type Events1 = | Wedding | Birthday 

 type Product = 
      | Retail of Retail1 | Wholesale of Wholesale1 | Events of Events1
      | NoProduct
```

I want to convert the possibility of the first three types to the Product type via a function:

```
 let convertToProduct (retail: Retail1 option) 
      (wholesale: Wholesale1   option) (events: Events1 option) =
      // convert to Product here
      if retail.IsSome then Retail retail
      elif wholesale.IsSome then Wholsale wholseale
      elif events.IsSome then Events events
      else NoProduct
```

The way that I have handled it in the pass is just to chain a long if elif statement together to check for each condition and return the final type of Product, but this does not feel correct, or at the very least idiomatic to F#. What would be the recommended approach to this problem?

Comment: Would it be possible to have input like: `convertToProduct (Some(Retail1.Fashion)) None (Some(Wedding))` ? If so then you will have to rethink your types.

Comment: Of interest: [Reasoning about functional types](http://tomasp.net/blog/types-and-math.aspx/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
let convertToProduct (retail: Retail1 option) (wholesale: Wholesale1 option) (events: Events1 option) =
    match (retail, wholesale, events) with
    |Some rt, None, None -> Retail rt
    |None, Some wh, None -> Wholesale wh
    |None, None, Some ev -> Events ev
    |_ -> NoProduct
```

This exploits the fact that if you convert all the arguments into a tuple, you can do pretty concise pattern matching on the result.

Pattern matching is actually extremely powerful, you can find more details about the types of pattern matching you can perform in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/pattern-matching-[fsharp]).